# Trying to open vb.net project to another version

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I try to open my project in vb.net in express edition 2010 but i create that project in professional edition and now theres an warning 
Here is the warning:

Namespace or type specified in the project-level Imports 'System.Xml.Linq' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.

Comment: The edition of VS shouldn't matter in that regard.  It sounds like you have lost a reference somehow.  Make sure that your project has a reference to the System.Xml.Linq.dll assembly.  If you are targeting the Client Profile of the Framework, you may have to change that to target the full Framework.

Comment: In Visual Studio which version.